# What is the right way to use a database with flutter?

Tags: mysql, flutter, dart

I have an app which interacts with the database directly with mysql1 library like the example below:

```
Future FetchData() async {
  final connection = await MySqlConnection.connect(ConnectionSettings(
    host: 'mysql-hostname.example.com',
    port: 3306,
    user: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    db: 'testDB',
  ));
  var results = await connection.query('SELECT * FROM `testTable` WHERE 1');
  for (var row in results) {
    print('${row[0]}');
  }

  // Finally, close the connection
  await connection.close();
}
```

I wonder if this is a safe and secure method. Because when I build the app I pack all the information (username, password) about connecting my database in the app. Is this risky so should I use a separate back-end for this kind of tasks?

Comment: For safest user authentication I think you should use [Firebase Auth](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_auth)

Answer (score 1):

It is generally safer to put a trusted backend environment between your database and app. But even in this case you will have to ensure that only your app has access to this backend resource.

For example if you use Firebase as backend, there is an [AppCheck](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/app-check/overview/) service available. Although this is relatively new, it can attest your app's authenticity.

If you prefer to do it on your own, you can create a bearer token that your app will add the the requests, preferably in the request's `Authorization` header, and check it in the backend before accessing protected resources. But then the question remains, where do you store this bearer token safely.

If you want to keep it in your code, you should properly [obfuscate](https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/obfuscate) the code before uploading it to the app stores. Even in this case it is a good idea to check for rooted or jailbroken devices to prevent misuse, for example check out [flutter_jailbreak_detection](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_jailbreak_detection).

There are also secure storage packages, which can store sensitive data in a safer way. Unlike `SharedPreferences`, these can mitigate the risks of unauthorited access to your secrets. See [flutter_secure_storage](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_secure_storage) for example.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the level of security that you are looking for. Are you storing user-generated sensitive information in your database? Then the answer is that you should ideally not store that information in your code nor should you ship your application with that information bundled inside it.

I highly suggest that you start using Firebase for your usage. Firebase is an absolutely fantastic and free product provided by the Google, the same company behind Flutter, and within a few minutes you can build a whole experience that relies on authentication with Firebase and you can safely store user-generated content in Firebase.

Comment: "free"?? it's a product with a free tier.